# Persistent Blurriness Issue in Label Printing for Windows

Tags: c#, windows, printing, maui

I am using [this](https://github.com/LanceMcCarthy/CustomMauiExamples/blob/main/src/DocumentPrinting/DocumentPrinting/Helpers/PrintHelper.Windows.cs) Print Helper class for my MAUI app.

I have identified a persistent issue where printed labels exhibit blurriness when utilizing the PrintHelper within the application. Interestingly, the problem does not occur when I download the PDF from the app to my computer and print it separately, resulting in clear and legible labels. I have not changed any code in the helper class.

In the accompanying image, the label on the left side was printed after downloading and printing without using the app, displaying a notably higher clarity. In contrast, the label on the right side, printed using the app's PrintHelper, appear blurry, rendering the barcode unreadable.

Thank you in advance.

[Label Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OKZS.jpg)